# Show multiple output-tabs in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, tabs, output

I've got two projects: **Server** and **Client**. I receive two separate outputs in two separate tabs for every project I run as seen on the following picture:

[image]

How do I split the output window and show both tabs at the same time?
I have looked around for a bit now and can't find a solution..

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible according to a topic found on netbeans.org: http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic55785.html